# Airline Fees for changing flight

Tags: fees-and-charges, turkish-airlines

I want to change my return flight and want to know the fees to change it and if i only have to pay a fee to Flighthub or also turkish airlines. I need the cost for both.

Comment: You haven't said where you're going from or to, what class of ticket, or what the terms of the ticket said when you purchased it

Comment: As those fees can vary widely, it probably makes more sense to ask your travel agent and/or the airline (or to check online in whatever “manage by booking” interface your travel agent may provide).

Comment: What do the T&C of your flight booking say about fees for changing the booking?

Answer (score 4):

Every ticket has different terms and conditions. These are the terms you need to agree to when you book. In most cases the price for a change will be the a change fee plus the price difference between the old and the new ticket, which can be all over the place. The change fee depends a lot on the airline and the type of ticket that you bought.

Things get even more complicated when you book through a 3rd party like Flighthub. They put their own fees on conditions on top of those of the airlines.

> I need the cost for both.

Call them up and ask